# How to return the (total) pagecount of external PDF files via XSL

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, xsl-fo, antenna-house

Is it possible to return the total page count of an external PDF file via XSL?
Does the AntennaHouse Formatter have an equivalent extention?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you can use a predefined CSS `counter(pages)` but I am curently not sure how you would put that into your XSLT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Java based XSLT processor which allows external function call (such as Saxon PE or EE), then Apache PDFBox will help you.

PDFBox: 
https://pdfbox.apache.org/

PDFBox’s PDDocument class has the method that returns page count of the target PDF. So you can get page count by following step:

1. Write Java class and static method.
2. Call it from XSLT styleshhet.

[Java sample code]

```
package com.acme.pdfutil;
import java.io.File;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
public class pdfDocument {
    /**
     * Get the page count of specified PDF file.
     * @param filePath 
     * @return Page count
     */
    public static int getPageCount(String filePath){
        File pdfFile = null;
        PDDocument pdfDoc = null;
        int pageCount = -1;
        try {
            pdfFile = new File(filePath);
            pdfDoc = PDDocument.load(pdfFile);
            pageCount = pdfDoc.getNumberOfPages();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("[getPageCount] " + e.getMessage());
        }
        finally {
            if (pdfDoc != null){
                try{
                    pdfDoc.close();
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    ;
                }
            }
        }
        return pageCount;
    }
}
```

[XSLT stylesheet]

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
 xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" 
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xmlns:acmejava="java:com.acme.pdfutil.pdfDocument"
>
…
<!-- Call external function -->
<xsl:variable name=”pdfPageCount” as="xs:integer" select="acmejava:getPageCount($pdfPath)"/>
…
```

Comment: You are using an outdated (and too complex) method to open PDF files. The correct way to do it is `PDDocument pdf = PDDocument.load(file);`.

Comment: Thank you. I wrote this code over several years ago when PDFBox is version 1.7(?). So I corrected it based on your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Not out of the box, no.  Ways to do it would include:

- Use a command line tool such as pdftk (https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-server/) that can report the number of pages.  Before running the XSLT to create the FO, you could run the tool on the PDF and save the result to a file, and you would then read the file during the XSLT processing.
- Less reliably, you could use `grep`, etc., on the PDF and save the output of that to a file to be read.  See, e.g., http://www.unix.com/printthread.php?t=55661&pp=40
- If you think that all your PDFs are readable as 'unparsed text' by XSLT, then you could read the PDF using `unparsed-text()` then use XSLT's regular expression ability to find the right string(s).
- You could use the XSLT extensions from the Print and Page Layout Community Group (https://www.w3.org/community/ppl/wiki/XSLTExtensions) from within your XSLT to get the area tree from an FO file that just contains your external PDF and count the number of pages in that.
- Before running your XSLT, you could run AHPDFXML from Antenna House (see https://www.antennahouse.com/antenna1/ahpdfxml-conversion-library/) to get an XML representation of your PDF, then your XSLT could count the number of pages in that XML.

Comment: Thank you! Your first mentioned solution is feasable for me. I´m generating an additional XML file with a small custom Java class now. This XML contains the PDF filename and the according pagecount. Via XSL I´m just reading the XML data with the document() function and have access to the data.